# Use php to compare the strings from a file,cannot get the correct answer

Tags: php, file, compare

I use PHP to read a line from a txt.But when I echo them both,they are the same.But when I use "==" to compare, it's opposite

This is to write：

```
$content = $time."\r\n".$user."\r\n".$star."\r\n".$comment."\r\n"."======================\r\n";
$fp=fopen($row['comment'],'a');
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

This is to read and compare:

```
$file = file($row['comment']);
                    foreach($file as &$line){
                        $file_arr[] = $line;
                        if($line == "======================"){
                            echo "123";
                        }
                    }
```

The result is that it cannot echo "123".

Comment: Does one of them have newlines or other whitespace? Use `var_dump()`

Comment: please share your code then we can easily understand

Comment: $row['comment'] is a txt file

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace is the problem - change the reader to be:-

```
$file = file($row['comment']);
foreach($file as &$line)
{
      $file_arr[] = $line;
      if(trim($line) == "======================"){
         echo "123";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non visible characters are driving you crazy? Trim newlines and carriage returns of both strings you are comparing. You can use md5 function to compare hashes of 2 strings to see if they are always different.

Comment: Yes,it is.I got it now.Thank you.